# Korean(hangul) text entry in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity, keyboard-layout, ibus, korean

I am trying to get a korean(hangul) text entry working in ubuntu 14.04. So far I installed ibus-hangul and added korean(hangul) to text entry and activated ibus in the language settings.

Now I experience the following.

If I click on the symbol in the right corner and click on keyboard layout for korean(hangul) it shows me the standard English(USA) layout.

Then I depending on whether ibus is activated or not, I can only enter korean(hangul), e.g. in firefox or libre writer, or not at all. I can never change from korean(hangul) to standard English.

Now the surprising thing is that everything works fine in the unity search thing. Here, I can switch between my differtent text entry options.

I would appreciate any help, since I remember having such problems with every version of ubuntu.

Comment: dont you need a keyboard thats multilingual enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

14.04 uses `ibus-hangul` 1.4.2-3, which unfortunately does not have the ability to switch between Korean and English within the input method.

To switch between English and Korean, you would need to switch the input method entirely using the indicator menu or using:

<kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> to cycle through your input sources and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> to cycle in reverse.

14.10 uses `ibus-hangul` 1.4.2+git20140818-1, which has added the ability to switch between English and Korean within the input method.

1. Choose Hangul from the `ibus` indicator.
2. Open the drop-down and choose `Setup`.
3. Look at the keybindings to toggle between English and Hangul while in Korean input. The default on an English language keyboard is <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>. You can change this to whatever works best for you.

[image: IbusHangul Setup]

If you prefer menus to keyboard shortcuts, you can also check/uncheck `Hangul mode` in the `ibus` indicator drop-down when Korean is activated.

To start with Hangul rather than English, check the `Start in Hangul mode` option in the setup.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The problem is that the setup menu above in my case is exaclty missing the hangul toggle key and the "Start in hangul mode" point.

Comment: I'm sorry. I was using 14.10 when using ibus-hangul the first time. I updated the answer.